# sampling rate and bit resolution for Scanning Probe Microscopy

Tags: sampling, resolution, bit-rate

I am trying to compare two products and see which one offers higher performance in terms of sampling rate and bit resolution.

Below are the specs I was able to gather from [product1](http://www.attocube.com/attocontrol/microscopy-controllers/asc500/)  and [product 2](http://www.specs-zurich.com/upload/cms/user/1602_SPECS_Brochure_Nanonis-BP5_RZ_web1.pdf). (I am not sure if I am looking at the relevant specs though.)

**Product 1**:
Input: ADC @ 400 kS/s, 18 bit
2 HF ADC inputs @ 50 MS/s, 16 bit
Output: DAC outputs @ 200 kS/s, 16 bit

**Product 2**:
Input: 20-bit @ 60 kS/s, 22-bit @ 1 kS/s (oversampling)
Output: 20-bit, 1-ppm precision, 1 MS/s

I think it's true that higher resolution in bits is going to result in better performance. However, it seems product 1 has a higher sampling rate.

Could someone tell me which product will result in finer resolution in both input and output and why?

Comment: Do you want resolution in time or resolution in voltage? They're two independent parameters.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "resolution in input" and "resolution in output".  Those are nonsensical terms.

Comment: @TimWescott  My apologies. I meant the size of each step when the measured analog signal gets converted into a series of steps by 'resolution in input' (ADC)and the size of each step when I order the box to ramp a voltage from 0 to 10V (DAC)  for example.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ideally, I would like to pick a product that is superior in both regards.

Comment: Well, neither of your options are better in both regards than the other. Product 1 has a better time resolution, and product 2 has a better voltage resolution.

Comment: @Hearth Thank you so much for your answer. So, if let's say the voltage value we are measuring changes as you move your microscope across a corrugated surface.  If we move the microscope head slow enough such that the time resolution is no longer a limiting factor (giving the scope head to take enough samples at a given spatial location, so to speak), it's the voltage resolution that matters more at that point.  Would you agree?

Comment: @Blackwidow I guess? I've never used an AFM before.